# How to remove special characters if it's only at the position of first and last in a string c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to remove special characters if it occurs as first and last char of a string .

code ;

```
  Regex.Replace(searchParams.SearchForText, @"(\s+|@|%|&|'|\(|\)|<|>|#)", "");
```

But it removes special characters even if it in the middle of the string .

```
ex : input : $input@text%
     output : input@text
```

Comment: Why Regex for this, just take a substring

Comment: If you know that the special may or maynot be first of last. Just check first and last char to see if they are special, then remove them.

Comment: I think you just need `Trim`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
var pattern = @"(?:\s+|[@%&'()<>#])";
var result = Regex.Replace(searchParams.SearchForText, $@"^{pattern}|{pattern}$", "");
```

See the resulting `^(?:\s+|[@%&'()<>#])|(?:\s+|[@%&'()<>#])$` [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%7C%5B%40%25%26%27%28%29%3C%3E%23%5D%29%7C%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%7C%5B%40%25%26%27%28%29%3C%3E%23%5D%29%24&i=%20%20%20Text%20here%23&r=).

If you need to remove all of these chars from start and/or end of string use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(searchParams.SearchForText, @"^[@%&'()<>#\s]+|[@%&'()<>#\s]+$", "");
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5Cs%40%25%26%27%28%29%3C%3E%23%5D%2B%7C%5B%5Cs%40%25%26%27%28%29%3C%3E%23%5D%2B%24&i=%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%28%20Text%20here%23%28%29%20%20%40%20%25&r=).

Here, note that all single charalternatives are joined into a single character class for more efficient search. They do not have to be escaped inside a character class, so the pattern is even cleaner.

Next, since `\s+` matches one or more whitespace chars, it cannot be merged with single char alternatives in a character class, so a non-capturing group with alternation is used, `(?:...|...)`.

The `^` anchor makes the first `^{pattern}` match only at the string start position, and the `$` anchor makes the second `{pattern}$` alternative match only at the end of string.

Since the `pattern` should be repeated twice, it is declared as a variable and the regex is built dynamically.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  it shows error as "expect )" in the following palce of the code "$@"^{pattern}|{pattern}$""

Comment: @Zhu Could you please show the snippet? [My code works fine](https://ideone.com/QDKzGc).

Comment: @Zhu There is another suggestion: `Regex.Replace(text.Trim(), @"^[@%&'()<>#]|[@%&'()<>#]$", "")` - trim the input, then replace the first/last chars that you want, see [another demo](https://ideone.com/Rs8ORL). Trim the result again if necessary.

Comment: @Zhu If you need to add `[` and `]` to the chars you need to remove, use `var pattern = @"(?:\s+|[][@%&'()<>#])";` or `@"^[][@%&'()<>#\s]+|[][@%&'()<>#\s]+$"`. To remove any non-word chars and `_` use `@"^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$"`. To remove any punctuation, symbols and whitespace, use ``@"^[\p{P}\p{S}\s]+|[\p{P}\p{S}\s]+$"``

Answer (score 3):

```
var specialChars = "$@%&'()<>#\u0020".ToCharArray();
var trimmed = "$input@text%".Trim(specialChars);
```

Comment: Upvote for `ToCharArray`. I love that trick for long sequences of trim characters.

Comment: `.Trim` removes all occurrences of the timmed chars at start and end, while OP needs to only remove them at the first and last position in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Possibly... but the question is honestly not very clear on that point. This certainly won't remove them from the middle of the string.

Comment: It is clear: *I am trying to remove special characters **if it occurs as first and last char of a string***

Comment: Remove the special character if it ocucurs as first **and** last char of a string?

Comment: At any rate, your suggestion will only work with regular spaces while OP also deals with any Unicode whitespace.

Comment: I'm not sure dealing with unicode whitespace is intentional. People might just use `\s` for removing just space and tab, but you made good points here, and the question needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 3):

You may simply use Trim()

```
var input = "$input@text%";
var output = input.Trim('@', '%', '$', '\'', '#');
```

Comment: @weichch You both forgot the whitespace trim though. Might I suggest adding `' '` and `'\t'` to the list?

Comment: @Nyerguds Mine trims space see that `\u0020`, but yeah, tab is another thing.

Comment: I noticed, but `'\u0020'` is a rather convoluted way of writing `' '` ;)

Comment: Yep, just used that to emphasize that space, because it's hard to read a space on post :)

Comment: `.Trim` removes all occurrences of the timmed chars at start and end, while OP needs to only remove them at the first and last position in the string. See *I am trying to remove special characters **if it occurs as first and last char of a string***.